# MSBuild publish project from tfs

Tags: tfs, msbuild

how can i publish a database project that resides on tfs using MSBuild?

when i use MSBuild /t:Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="Database1.publish.xml" "$/FinalBuild/Database1.sqlproj" 
i get the error :
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can't point MSBuild to a TFS Source Control location.  You need to get a copy of the source and then use MSBuild locally, either this is on your dev machine or a build server.

You can only build files that are local to the location that you are building.